# Get coords of Real Estate

Tags: xml, r, web-scraping, rcurl

my task is to download as many flat sell offers as I can. I have script for downloading links and other stuff, but I can't get coordinates of flats (it crucial to me, main point of my analysis).

Coordinates are visible on the website (by checking google map element) but not in the source of the website.

When I use below R Code I get an empty list, no difference if i use XML or RCurl package.

Do you think it is possible to achieve this using R or should I thing about other programming languages (eg. Python?)

```
library(XML)
library(RCurl)
url<-'http://en.otodom.pl/flat-poznan-jezyce-2720m2-2-rooms-125000-pln-id13250586.html'
doc<-htmlParse(url,encoding='utf-8')
xpathApply(doc,'//div[@id="googleMap"]',xmlGetAttr,'data-map')

#the same result
doc<-getURL(url, httpheader = c('User-Agent' = "Informative string with your contact info"),.encoding='utf-8')
doc<-htmlParse(doc,encoding='utf-8')
xpathApply(doc,'//div[@id="googleMap"]',xmlGetAttr,'data-map')

# the same here
doc<-getURL(url, followlocation=T)
doc<-htmlParse(doc,encoding='utf-8')
xpathApply(doc,'//div[@id="googleMap"]',xmlGetAttr,'data-map')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is basically right, but it downloads a page without the coordinates in it. Clicking on the Maps link activates an Ajax request to pull in the Google Map and you need to parse the second mini-page to find the coordinates. I have packaged that into a function. Pass in the url of a page on that site. It will pull down that page, scrape the data id, call in the Google Map and scrape the coordinates from it.

```
library(XML)
library(RCurl)

get.coords <- function(url) {
    doc<-htmlParse(url,encoding='utf-8')
    data.ins.id <- getNodeSet(doc,'//@data-ins-id')
    data.ins.id <- as.character(data.ins.id[[1]]["data-ins-id"])

    mapurl <- paste('http://en.otodom.pl/?mod=show&act=showMap&insId=', 
                    data.ins.id, 
                    sep='')
    doc <- htmlParse(mapurl,encoding='utf-8')
    result <- getNodeSet(doc,'//@data-map')
    result <- as.character(result[[1]]["data-map"])
    return(strsplit(result, "|", fixed=TRUE)[[1]][c(1,2)])
}

url <- 'http://en.otodom.pl/flat-poznan-jezyce-2720m2-2-rooms-125000-pln-id13250586.html'
coords <- get.coords(url)
coords
```

Comment: Glad it is useful @Maciej. :) It is up to you, of course, to check that it is legal to scrape the site and use the data for your purpose, as well as to be a good citizen and pace your queries so you don't flood the site...